# Python: select or poll on threading.event

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, sockets

I was reading recently that the BSD `kqueue` can take all kinds of events and not just file descriptors. But for Linux users it looks like something like this: 
(from socketserver python stdlib)

```
#self being passed to select is a listening socket
try:
    while not self.__shutdown_request:
        # XXX: Consider using another file descriptor or
        # connecting to the socket to wake this up instead of
        # polling. Polling reduces our responsiveness to a
        # shutdown request and wastes cpu at all other times.
        r, w, e = _eintr_retry(select.select, [self], [], [],
                               poll_interval)
        if self in r:
            self._handle_request_noblock()

        self.service_actions()
```

Is there some clever way to to check a `threading.Event()` with `select` or `poll` or is it an inevitable situation that one has to connect a second socket to listen for a shutdown event?

edit: What I would be looking for is something like this: 
`select.select([self, clever_wrapper(self.__shutdown_request)], [], [])`

Answer (score -2):

> Is there some clever way to to check a threading.Event() with select or poll or is it an inevitable situation that one has to connect a second socket to listen for a shutdown event?

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to detect a shutdown of the peer you can simply do this with select and poll followed by a read. That is if select/poll return that the socket is read for reading and you then read and return no data but no error either, then you know that the peer issued a shutdown.

There is no need for a second socket and of course a second connection could not even detect if the first connection has been closed.

Comment: No, you're not trying to detect if the peer was shutdown- it's your own process (or maybe another thread) that's calling your (in this case server) with a shutdown event.

Comment: So you want to detect from thread A if thread B closed the socket? If you try select/poll it will throw in error because you are using an invalid file descriptor. kqueue would not help here too.

Comment: You want to detect `self.__shutdown_request:` without running a `while` loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intention. You want to explicitly shutdown a socket but you don't like to tell any other thread about it and hope they get notified somehow even if they don't read/write/select at this socket?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear - you want to find out if the server received a shutdown request, without running a while loop and constantly timing-out your select to check if a shutdown request came in.

Comment: You might use an internal socket for notification between threads, e.g. thread A writes something  into this socket once it has done a relevant activity (like closing the connection to some peer). If you do a select/poll with other sockets in  thread  B you just add the communication socket too and thus the poll/select returns once thread A wrote the event. With kqueue you would need to use a similar approach.

Comment: As far as I understood from reading about kqueue the objects don't need to have file descriptors  - the second socket for notifications between threads is what I mentioned in my question - I was just wondering if maybe there was a more clever trick.

Comment: Now I understand what you did mean with the second file descriptor in your original question. Yes, kqueue can not only do file descriptors but it has a limited set of events (fd, signal, timer, process end...)  and no general publish/subscribe mechanism for arbitrary events. Since select can be disrupted with signals you might try this, but this might not be a portable solution. I don't see any usable way apart from the internal socket.